# Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "Error "" at line 1, column 2

Tags: apache-pig

I have a simple pig script used to import data file.

My data file is located in : /home/fs188

It's a csv file which contains data as :

```
011958029,00000024,,1,20100209,1
011951228,00000036,,1,20100209,1
011964431,00000814,,1,20100227,1
003526500,00000863,,1,20080122,1
011950864,00001478,,1,20100209,1
011999168,00002495,X0,1,20100331,0
001684881,00002641,,1,19861126,1
001677981,00003165,,1,19861119,1
001677457,00003311,,1,19870114,1
001677161,00003440,,1,19870116,1
002594705,00003475,,1,19870122,1
011958074,00004327,,1,20100210,1
```

I just want to execute my script pig named PigScript and test it in local mode.

It contains this code :

```
ENEE_ENR_FILTER = LOAD '/home/fs188/DataExempleUdf.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (idt_gcp:chararray,idt_ent_pse:chararray,cd_not:chararray,idc_pse_pci:chararray,da_pram_ett:chararray,idc_cd_not:chararray);

DUMP ENEE_ENR_FILTER;
```

So I call my script :

```
pig -x local PigScript.pig
```

I get this error :

> 2019-08-07 12:03:14,277 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  "-x "" at line 1, column 2.

This is weird because I don't have any synthax error